# Serial correlation requirements for Mann-Kendall test

Tags: autocorrelation, stationarity, trend

I want to apply the Mann-Kendall (MK) test to identify relevant trends in multiple time series, however literature on the matter tells me one hard requirement is for no serial correlation to exist in the data.
In its turn, conventional auto-correlation analysis using ACF/PACF plots require stationarity, which is usually dealt with by differentiating the time series.

My question is:
is this approach compatible with the requirements of the MK test (as differentiating removes the underlying trends)? Or rather, can I conclude the original series is not serially correlated from the analysis of its differentiated series?